# Link between Poisson and Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability

Let $Y_1, Y_2,  \cdots$ be independent Ber($p$) random variables defined on the same probability space. Prove that $$X := \sum_{i=1}^{X_1} Y_i$$ also has the law of Poi($pλ$) and $X_1 − X$ has
the law of Poi($(1 − p)λ$) and is independent of $X$.

I really struggle to show this, the sum depending on $X_1$ is not helping me and have difficulties to compute $\mathbb P(X=k)$.
How should I start ?

Comment: What is $X_1$ ?

Comment: Hint: Write $P(X=k) = \sum_{n} P(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i =k)P(X_1=n)$